# Background image disappears whenever I try to alter its dimensions

Tags: html, css

The image displays when I use this code:

```
body {
    background-image: url("iuerghreugh.jpg")
}
```

but when I use the code below, the image I use for my background simply disappears. I'm very new to HTML and CSS so I feel I could be missing something very basic.

```
body {
    background-image: url("iuerghreugh.jpg")
    background-size: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please share a working example on for example JSfiddle.net

Comment: You forgot to add the semi-colon after the background-image.

Answer (score 3):

There's no semicolon after the first rule:

```
background-image: url("iuerghreugh.jpg")
//--------------------------------------^ Add a semicolon ; here.
```

**Solution**

```
body {
  background-image: url("iuerghreugh.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the semicolon after the url line

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

missing semicolon at the end of background image property

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is missing after `url` for `background-image`. You can also consider combining everything, as in the following:

```
body { background: url("iuerghreugh.jpg") 0 0 / 100% 50% no-repeat; }
```

In the above, 0 0 before the `/` is for position, and after `/` is for size.